# Validation on Table rows

Tags: angularjs

I want to make validations on table rows , I am doing in the following way but its not working.
I want to apply it on click of save button at lst.

I have 5 columns and want to apply validation for each column Suppose if any field is empty I want to disable the button.
Can anybody help?

```js
<div class="mainDiv" ng-if="currentForm != ''">
    <table class="mappingTable">
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>CommCare Question</th>
            <th>Data Element</th>
            <th>Category Option Combo</th>
            <th>Frequency/Period</th>
            <th>Facility Identifier</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="mappingElement in formIdMetadataMappingToObjectMap[currentForm.unique_id].mappingElements">
            <td class="serialNoCell">{{$index+1}}.</td>
            <td title="{{mappingElement.commcareQuestion}}" class="commcareQuestion">{{mappingElement.commcareQuestionDescription}}</td>
            <td class="dhisDe"> <input type="text"
                                       name="foo"
                                       class="form-control"

                                       ng-model="mappingElement.dataElement"
                                       ng-class="{ error: !mappingElement.dataElement }"
                                       placeholder="{{'please_select_data_element'}}"
                                       uib-typeahead="dataElement as dataElement.name for dataElement in dataElements | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:20"
                                       uib-typeahead-focus-first="false"
                                       uib-typeahead-editable=false
                                       ng-blur="updateCategoryCombo(this.mappingElement)"
                    /></td>
            <td class="dhisCC"><input type="text"
                                      name="foo"
                                      class="form-control"
                                      ng-model="mappingElement.categoryCombo"
                                      ng-class="{ error: !mappingElement.categoryCombo }"
                                      placeholder="{{'please_select_categorycombo'}}"
                                      uib-typeahead="categoryComboOption as categoryComboOption.name for categoryComboOption in categoryComboInputHolder[currentForm.unique_id+mappingElement.commcareQuestion] | filter:$viewValue "
                                      uib-typeahead-focus-first="false"
                                      uib-typeahead-editable=false
                    /></td>
            <td class="dhisPeriod"><input type="text"
                                          name="foo"
                                          class="form-control"
                                          ng-model="mappingElement.period"
                                          ng-class="{ error: !mappingElement.period }"
                                          placeholder="{{'please_select_period'}}"
                                          uib-typeahead="period as period.name for period in periods | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:20"
                                          uib-typeahead-focus-first="false"
                                          uib-typeahead-editable=false
                    /></td>
            <td class="dhisOuIdentifier"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="commcareQuestionToOrgUnitIdentifierMap[currentForm.unique_id+mappingElement.commcareQuestion]" ng-click="doOrgUnitUIOperations(this);" ng-disabled="!commcareQuestionToOrgUnitIdentifierMap[currentForm.unique_id+mappingElement.commcareQuestion]&&formIdToIsOrgUnitIdentifierPresentMap[currentForm.unique_id]"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <div>
        
        <button type="button"  ng-disabled="!mappingElement.categoryCombo || !mappingElement.dataElement || !mappingElement.period"   ng-click="saveMetadataMapping()">{{'Save'}}</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing that could be wrong here is that the button is outside of the ng-repeat's scope. So it doesn't know about `mappingElement`. 
If you want validation on each row separately add the button inside a column,
otherwise you can create a function in the controller to iterate the `formIdMetadataMappingToObjectMap[currentForm.unique_id].mappingElements` collection and search for empty values, then you can simply add it to the button `ng-disabled="validationFunc()"`.